# jQuery cannot preserve data after .ajax() call

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, variables

I am trying to do a simple call where I get data back from $.ajax() and would like to save it into a global variable which I can use in a function that called the ajax call.

Why is the variable not being set? Why is the value that I set gets lost?

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;

$.myNamespace = {
    timerID: "in namespace"
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSkip").click(function () {
        alert($.myNamespace.timerID);
        startCall();
    });

    function startCall() {
        $.myNamespace.timerID = "in startCall()";
        alert($.myNamespace.timerID);
        finishCall();
        alert($.myNamespace.timerID);
    }

    function finishCall() {
        $.myNamespace.timerID = "in finishCall()";
        alert($.myNamespace.timerID);

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: getUrl,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.myNamespace.timerID = "in ajax succeeded call";
                alert($.myNamespace.timerID);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                GetSongInfoFailed(xhr, status, error);
            }
        });
    }

    function GetSongInfoFailed(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Service call failed: ' + xhr + ' ' + status + ' ' + error);
    }


});
```

Output from `alert()`s in above code:

1. `in namespace`
2. `in startCall()`
3. `in finishCall()`
4. `in ajax succeeded call`
5. `in finishCall()`

Why is the last variable is set to "in finishCall()" instead of "in ajax succeeded call"?

Note, I am not a jQuery or javascript expert.

Thank you so much!

Comment: stop using alerts for debugging use console.log(message) instead. You can either use firebug in firefox or dev tools in safari or chrome. You'll be much happier if you do so.

Comment: thank you i'll try. this was suppose to be a 5 min project. Ended up being hours because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your success callback function

```
 function GetSongInfoSucceeded(C) {
        if (result != null) {

            $.myNamespace.timerID = "in ajax succeeded call";
            alert($.myNamespace.timerID);

        } else { }

    }
```

You have an invalid `request` variable where as your function gets `C` as input data

Answer (score 0):

So, when you receive data, funct. is called:

```
GetSongInfoSucceeded(data);
```

If we look at your function definition:

```
function GetSongInfoSucceeded(C) {
```

then we see, than an input of "data" will now be inside var called `C`. That is why calling `result` won't give you any answer:

```
        if (result != null) {

            $.myNamespace.timerID = "in ajax succeeded call";
            alert($.myNamespace.timerID);

        } else { }
```

Correct way would be something like this:

```
function GetSongInfoSucceeded(result) {
    if (result != null) {
        $.myNamespace.timerID = "in ajax succeeded call";
        alert($.myNamespace.timerID);
    } else { }
}
```

Comment: yes that's not the problem. Actually I assign variable directly in on success too and even that does not work. I changed it to "result" too. Still nothing.

Comment: removed and modified code. still same issue. MAybe now its more clear... thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a question of preserving data - it's actually a question of execution order. Let's check your code again, this time replacing the finishCall() call with actual code of the function:

```
alert($.myNamespace.timerID);

$.myNamespace.timerID = "in finishCall()";
alert($.myNamespace.timerID);

$.ajax({..., ..., function() {     
  $.myNamespace.timerID = "in ajax succeeded call()";
  alert($.myNamespace.timerID);
});

alert($.myNamespace.timerID);
```

See, JS won't wait for $.ajax call to succeed before it calls the last `alert`. And when it does, the value would be still `in finishCall()`.

What puzzles me is why this `alert` is shown the last, as you say, and not the one before the last; with `console.log` the 'ajax succeed call' gets shown the last actually.

Comment: yes you are right. This is what I am thinking the problem is. The sequence of events and the async call. However, I need these functions being separate one from the other because they get called repetitively from different places. I am puzzled as well.